# Neo4j: Faster subgraph coloring/labelling

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph containing multiple small subgraphs. The goal is to mark all the BLUE nodes of a subgraph as RED if and only if all the nodes within that subgraph is BLUE. If one of the node in a subgraph has different color, GREEN, then we will not change the color of the nodes in that subgraph.

This is the query I am using:

```
MATCH (a:BLUE) WHERE NOT (a)-[*]-(:GREEN) WITH a LIMIT 10000 SET a:RED REMOVE a:BLUE
```

This is how it looks before and after the query:
[image]

**The problem is that it is slow as it needs to traverse same subgraph multiple times.** For example:

To mark A as RED it needs to traverse A-B-C. Then again, to mark B it needs to traverse A-B-C. Again, the same to mark C.

**I would to know if there is any way I can mark all the nodes in the subgraph in one go instead of visiting the same subgraph again and again.** If that is possible then it will reduce the query time by many factors.

Comment: Would it be helpful to first mark all the subgraphs using neo4j graph algorithms plugin... docs https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_connected_components

Comment: @TomažBratanič in the original use case all the nodes which are older than a particular timestamp are labelled as BLUE. As such, union-find/connected component will help if we can assign whole subgraph the timestamp of the latest node in the subgraph. But will be very costly as it means I need to traverse the whole graph. Instead in my case I am isolating the nodes which are older than a particular timestamp and then only traversing those nodes.

Comment: @TomažBratanič Looks good, but is this ready for use yet? My attempts keep giving me NoSuchMethodErrors when using the documented name, parameters, and yields.

Comment: I tried the examples with the first release and they all work... are you using neo4j 3.2.x ? It might not work there yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the graph algorithms plugin yet, but this can often be done faster that pure Cypher using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths), though all nodes in all relevant subgraphs do need to be processed to distill down to a single row for a connected subgraph, as Neo4j has no native support for subgraph querying.

The procedure `apoc.path.subgraphNodes()` in particular is helpful for expanding out to the entire subgraph from each node, and will only calculate a single path to each node rather than evaluating all possible paths.

From there, we can group by the minimal node in the subgraph and keep only one set of nodes representing the entire subgraph. This gets us to one row per subgraph, which lets our predicate to check the color of all nodes in the subgraph run only once per subgraph.

Something like this:

```
MATCH (n:BLUE) // no need to get subgraphs that don't have blue nodes
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n, {}) YIELD node
WITH n, collect(node) as nodes, min(id(node)) as minId
WITH minId, head(collect(nodes)) as nodes // now only one row / subgraph
WHERE all(node in nodes where node:BLUE)
UNWIND nodes as node
SET node:RED
REMOVE node:BLUE
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working great. I tried to batch the whole process using apoc periodic iteration. 

***
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate( "MATCH (n:BLUE) CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n, {}) YIELD node WITH n , collect(node) as nodes, min(id(node)) as minId WITH minId, head(collect(nodes)) as nodes WHERE all(node in nodes where node:Marked) return nodes ", "UNWIND nodes as node SET node:RED REMOVE node:BLUE", {batchSize:10000, parallel:true, iterateList:true})

***

However I am getting the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error. Basically heap overflow.

Comment: You may want to try changing the boundaries of your inner and outer query. Maybe try iteration over just your starting blue nodes, `MATCH (n:BLUE)`, and play around a bit with the batchSize, since your heap will need to accommodate expansion to the entire subgraphs of every :BLUE node in your batch.